# Vaadin with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, firebase-realtime-database, vaadin

I'm trying to show a notification for extracted data. For some reason the data is successfully extracted but the notification is not shown. Mind you the notification is shown when not inside the onDataChange method.

```
` public HomeNew() {
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
    verticalLayout.setWidthFull();
    button = new Button("TestBUTTON");

    button.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComponentEvent(ClickEvent<Button> buttonClickEvent) {
            UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                Notification extractedDataNotification = Notification
                        .show("Extracted Data: " + "data");
                extractedDataNotification.addThemeVariants(NotificationVariant.LUMO_SUCCESS);
            });
            DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Extract data from Firebase
                    String data = dataSnapshot.child("data").getValue(String.class);
                    logger.info("Extracted Data: " + data);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Handle onCancelled event if needed
                }
            });

        }
    });

    verticalLayout.add(button);
    add(verticalLayout);`
```

This code works, when the notification is outside of onDataChange.

```
`public HomeNew() {
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
    verticalLayout.setWidthFull();
    button = new Button("TestBUTTON");

    button.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComponentEvent(ClickEvent<Button> buttonClickEvent) {
            DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Extract data from Firebase
                    String data = dataSnapshot.child("data").getValue(String.class);
                    logger.info("Extracted Data: " + data);
                    UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                        Notification extractedDataNotification = Notification
                                .show("Extracted Data: " + data);
                        extractedDataNotification.addThemeVariants(NotificationVariant.LUMO_SUCCESS);
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Handle onCancelled event if needed
                }
            });
          
        }
    });

    verticalLayout.add(button);
    add(verticalLayout);`
```

This one doesn't work when the notification is inside the onDataChange method, which is what I need.Also the logs indicate the data is being extracted succesfully.
`2024-03-02T21:41:55.703+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [se-event-target] com.example.application.views.Database   : Extracted Data: Hello this is data`

Some logs. I am also initializing firebase with a different section of code not included.
`

---

|  /  |_   _     / \   _ __  _ __
| |/| | | | |   / _ \ | '_ | '_ \
| |  | | |*| |  / ___ | |*) | |*) |
|*|  |*|_*, | /*/   _\ .**/| .**/
|*__/          |*|   |*|

2024-03-02T21:41:23.660+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : Starting Application using Java 21.0.1 with PID 13072 (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\new app\my-app\target\classes started by Admin in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\new app\my-app)
2024-03-02T21:41:23.678+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-02T21:41:23.892+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-03-02T21:41:23.893+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-03-02T21:41:28.417+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-03-02T21:41:28.449+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-02T21:41:28.450+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-03-02T21:41:28.683+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-02T21:41:28.686+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4788 ms
Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
2024-03-02T21:41:28.710+03:00  WARN 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : vaadin.whitelisted-packages is deprecated and may not be supported in the future. Use vaadin.allowed-packages instead.
2024-03-02T21:41:31.166+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 1862 ms
2024-03-02T21:41:32.942+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.b.d.startup.DevModeStartupListener   : Starting dev-mode updaters in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\new app\my-app folder.
2024-03-02T21:41:33.132+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.f.s.FullDependenciesScanner      : Visited 116 classes. Took 131 ms.
2024-03-02T21:41:33.136+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.frontend.BundleValidationUtil    : Checking if a development mode bundle build is needed
2024-03-02T21:41:34.189+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.frontend.BundleValidationUtil    : A development mode bundle build is not needed
2024-03-02T21:41:34.307+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles   : Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
2024-03-02T21:41:34.615+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles   : Visited 20 resources. Took 309 ms.
2024-03-02T21:41:34.616+03:00 ERROR 13072 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.FCMInitializer   : class path resource [classpath:serviceaccount.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2024-03-02T21:41:36.129+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-03-02T21:41:36.508+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration   :
Vaadin is running in DEVELOPMENT mode - do not use for production deployments.
2024-03-02T21:41:36.685+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-03-02T21:41:36.714+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : Started Application in 14.489 seconds (process running for 17.618)
2024-03-02T21:41:37.063+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-02T21:41:37.064+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-02T21:41:37.079+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2024-03-02T21:41:39.112+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator  : The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
2024-03-02T21:41:49.667+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.example.application.views.Database   : Firebase application has been initialized successfully
2024-03-02T21:41:55.703+03:00  INFO 13072 --- [se-event-target] com.example.application.views.Database   : Extracted Data: Hello this is data
`

Comment: I have no idea how the `data` variable is used in showing the notification, but **any code that needs to use that data has to be inside `onDataChange`, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized**.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: The notification should display whatever is the data string. If the logger is successfully showing it I should also see the Notification with the value of data. But for some reason the notification is not shown at all, not even with an empty string.

Comment: Shot in the dark: `UI.getCurrent()` does not work/return a UI, because
this code inside `onDataChange` runs async. Have you tried capturing the
UI in a variable? And in case there is even an error, that gets
hidden/eaten somewhere, I'd suggest solving that too.